# How do I set up an HP remote control?

Tags: hardware, remote, boxee

I have an old receiver (USB) and remove control that i am trying to get working on Ubuntu with Boxee.

Any suggestions for setting this up? software I need.

Comment: What kind of remote is it? Do you have specific model information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install `gnome-lirc-properties` "Infrared Remote Control" from Ubuntu Software Center or

`sudo apt-get install gnome-lirc-properties`

It will set up the configuration for your remote in lirc and allow you to test the remote.

After setting that up you need to set up your remote with boxee file. Next Boxee needs a config file for the remote. Copy `/opt/boxee/system/Lircmap.xml` to `$HOME/.boxee/Lircmap.xml`.

Now open the Lircmap.xml copy that is in the UserData folder, and add the code from [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=6441867&postcount=2) forum post just before the ending  tag:

```
<remote device="Streamzap_PC_Remote">
    <pause>PAUSE</pause>
    <stop>STOP</stop>
    <forward>&gt;&gt;</forward>
    <reverse>&lt;&lt;</reverse>
    <left>LEFT</left>
    <right>RIGHT</right>
    <up>UP</up>
    <down>DOWN</down>
    <select>OK</select>
    <pageplus>CH_UP</pageplus>
    <pageminus>CH_DOWN</pageminus>
    <back>EXIT</back>
    <menu>MENU</menu>
    <title>PLAY</title>
    <info>More</info>
    <skipplus>&gt;&gt;|</skipplus>
    <skipminus>|&lt;&lt;</skipminus>
    <display>Teletext</display>
    <start>Home</start>
    <record>RECORD</record>
    <volumeplus>VOL_UP</volumeplus>
    <volumeminus>VOL_DOWN</volumeminus>
    <mute>MUTE</mute>
    <power>POWER</power>
    <myvideo>Videos</myvideo>
    <mymusic>Music</mymusic>
    <mypictures>Pictures</mypictures>
    <mytv>TV</mytv>
    <one>1</one>
    <two>2</two>
    <three>3</three>
    <four>4</four>
    <five>5</five>
    <six>6</six>
    <seven>7</seven>
    <eight>8</eight>
    <nine>9</nine>
    <zero>0</zero>
    <mytv>RED</mytv>
    <mymusic>GREEN</mymusic>
    <mypictures>YELLOW</mypictures>
    <myvideo>BLUE</myvideo>
</remote>
```

Edit the keys for your particular remote.

Save the file and open Boxee, and the remote should now work.